# Why isn't Juypter notebook working on my raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I have installed Jupyter notebook on a fresh install of debian for pi. I had it working perfectly on a previous install. I do not understand why it is not working on this install. Kernal will not start.

```
@raspberrypi:~ $ jupyter notebook
[I 14:14:54.030 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/pi
[I 14:14:54.031 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 14:14:54.031 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=3d0f751a532a4e1a3744a1a49701fbde9a17d1d95fda43ca
[I 14:14:54.032 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=3d0f751a532a4e1a3744a1a49701fbde9a17d1d95fda43ca
[I 14:14:54.033 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 14:14:54.249 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/pi/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-837-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=3d0f751a532a4e1a3744a1a49701fbde9a17d1d95fda43ca
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=3d0f751a532a4e1a3744a1a49701fbde9a17d1d95fda43ca
[I 14:15:26.196 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 9c892a78-7ef2-4d36-9649-d46392e26bb7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py)
[I 14:15:32.162 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application' from 'prompt_toolkit.shortcuts' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts/__init__.py)
[I 14:15:35.190 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), keep random ports
```

$

Is anyone able to shine some light on my situation?

Answer (score 0):

change the ownership of the ~/.local/share/jupyter directory from root to pi using below cmd:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Run this command if your kernel does not start or shows any issue it worked for me
"pip3 install --force-reinstall --upgrade jupyter"